What is the alternative API for Safari iOS for 'webRequest.onBeforeRequest' since this API is not available on Safari iOS?
I am working on a Safari extension for an AdBlocker. I want to use the JavaScript API 'webRequest.onBeforeRequest' for content blocking with 'updateDynamicRules,' but it's not available on Safari iOS. What is the alternative API for this?
Doc Link :- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest
is there any Alternate API or solution for this
